# How can a Gated Check-in be configured in tfs 2015 "vNext" builds?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, tfs-2015, gated-checkin

The new build system is pretty exciting.  But...

I would like to know if there's any way to create a build definition with a *gated checkin* using TFS Version Control like it's available in XAML build definition?

Is it a hidden option or difficult to find? If not, is it possible to develop an extension to do that or must we wait for MS to support it?

Comment: It seems to be a request on the VisualStudio UserVoice... https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/8775376-add-gated-check-in-support-in-build-vnext

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<s>Not currently, this is currently [scheduled](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/release-archive-vso.aspx) for Q4 2015 for vso and in Update 2 for TFS on prem.</s>

---

**Update 03/02/2016**: this has been [pushed back](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/release-archive-vso.aspx) to Q1 2016 for vso but still in Update 2 for TFS on prem (which I would assume is also pushed back).

---

**Update 31/03/2016**: In [Update 2](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/tfs2015-update2-vs.aspx), released 30th March, [gated checkin support](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/tfs2015-update2-vs.aspx#gatedcheck) for TFVC was shipped.

This now shows on the Triggers tab of a build definition:
[image]

Comment: :0 how does that not make v1

Comment: @felickz tell me about it :\

Comment: It was postponed to Q1 2016

Comment: @Chesheersky Oh that makes me a sad panda. :-\